# Process Monitor Troubleshooting custom print driver, print spooler

Tags: printing, printer-control-language, process-explorer

Our users upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. 
When they try to print using a custom print driver they get this error

```
The document Print Document, owned by User, failed to print on printer TEST-PRINT. Try to print the document again, or restart the print spooler. 
Data type: NT EMF 1.008. Size of the spool file in bytes: 628788. Number of bytes printed: 12900. Total number of pages in the document: 6. Number of pages printed: 0. 
Client computer: Devcomp. Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 2147500037. Unspecified error
```

Some of my  observations: Internally we cannot reproduce this error internally. I have a windows 10 surface and also tried on a windows 8 machine.  Our support tried it here too. 
The customer can reproduce the issue without. The issue happens for some documents on some workstations. The PDF is generated from a 3rd party application for tellers. The customer saves the pdf from this signature desktop application to a PDF and uses our print driver to print to the our application. 
Our print driver converts the file to PCL and sends it to the subscriber for further processing. 
I can provide more info if needed regarding print driver. First of is it a problem with the print driver?

All the users who upgraded from windows 7  to a windows 10 laptop can see the issue happening. There are some windows 10 workstations that print just fine.  Could it be something with the group policy or some registry settings. If I were to compare the registry or policies on the workstation that prints and the one that fails what would be the settings I need to look for? The customer's IT says that there is no difference between the two workstations except that it’s the production workstation that fails. Typical response nothing different but it doesn't work.

We also tried to disable “render print jobs on the client workstation” but this didn’t seem to make difference. I am happy to try any suggestions you’ll have.

I am looking for ideas of what kind of research and where should I start troubleshooting.
I won't be troubled if anyone chooses to vote the question down that I didn't do any research since I really don't know where to start. I am a .NET developer not a windows driver expert or systems admin.

Process Monitor Good File. The file gets created.
Create file success, create file name not found and finally create file succcess

[image]

Bad File: Create file success, create file name not found. The last create file is not called by the print.exe driver.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem. Thanks Papercut!.

https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/FixingPrintSpoolerCrashes
https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/EnableAdvancedPrintingFeatures